# NuGet can't find a OxyPlot.Wpf package that is compatible to the OxyPlot.Core package

Tags: wpf, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers, oxyplot

I installed the OxyPlot.Core package by typing

```
Install-Package OxyPlot.Core -Pre
```

which worked fine. Then I tried to install the OxyPlot.Wpf package by typing

```
Install-Package OxyPlot.Wpf -Pre
```

but it can't find a package that is compatible to the OxyPlot.Core although the version seems to be the same:

> Install-Package : Die Version von "OxyPlot.Core", die mit 'OxyPlot.Wpf 1.0.0-unstable1849 Einschränkung: OxyPlot.Core (= 1.0.0-unstable1849)' kompatibel ist, wurde nicht gefunden.In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
>   + Install-Package OxyPlot.Wpf -Pre
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I also tried to install the correct version by typing

```
Install-Package OxyPlot.Wpf -Version 1.0.0-unstable1849 -Pre
```

without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now working! I uninstalled the Core Version and could then install the WPF package. The Core dependencies have been automatically installed.